# What's the efficient way to implement this dynamic table size in the VIEW (haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am going to render a haml or html table in my view (index.html.haml).

I have a string array which holds the value of true or false, like this:

```
str=['true', 'false', 'true', 'true', 'false']
```

There are 5 elements in the string array,the elements in the string array is dynamic based on user's input. Each of this element means 
`['display_color','display_size','display_shape', 'display_owner','display_price']`,

if it is true, the table will display that property in a column.

So, Based on the "true-false" string array, I will render a haml or html table with the rule that if the value is true, the table will display the proper 'display_*' in a column, otherwise, does not show the property in the table.

For example, if the string array holds the value like above, my table will have columns of "`display_color`" "`display_shape`" and "`display_owner`", since they are set to true in the array.

In haml or HTML, how can I write a block of efficient code to render this dynamic size table?? any example?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it :

```
%table
  %tbody
    -str.each_with_index do |s, i|
      -if s == 'true'
        %td=array[i]
```

You can apply the same logic for headers, etc...

Answer (score -1):

If you're really worried about efficiency don't use a string array to store boolean values. Mind you that's probably out of your hands because it's probably coming from a form control and the best they do is integers.

Are these columns properties of a model?
If so then the most efficient way would probably be writing a helper that takes the array and determines which properties to show. Otherwise go with Dhruva Sagar's answer.

Sorry, I haven't got the time to write a helper for you right now. Later today I'll edit one in.